# Installation of MYOB ODBC Driver fails on x64

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, myob

Using either the v19 test drive software to install Premier v19 or the NZ_ODBCv7013.exe file to install the v7 ODBC driver.  Both of these methods work on 32 bit systems but fail to install anything on x64 - there were no error msgs either.

Am I using the right install files?
Has anyone completed this installation successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install had worked and the v9 ODBC driver (from v19 test drive) is the recommended version.  The only trick is that the ODBC administrator must be run from this location:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: Here's an MS article on the subject that explains the situation rather well: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976

Comment: This method still fails for me. I get error message: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"}